# Need to populate Account Name when Flow runs from Account Detail Action Button for a task

Tags: button, custom, action

I have a task screen flow that runs just fine from task action button and assigns account.  I need to have an Action button to run this flow from the Account details page header and still have it populate the account id so the task gets assigned to the correct account.  Is this possible?  It runs fine but obviously gets sent into space with no Account assigned.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a text variable called `recordId` (case sensitive), Salesforce will auto-populate it with the ID of the record where invoked the screen flow.  See [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_actions_considerations.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5):

> Flow actions let you pass the value of the record's ID field into the
> flow, but that's it. If your flow has a Text input variable called
> recordId, the action passes the record's ID into that variable at
> runtime